# Date change event not firing in browser when selecting date in react-date picker by using puppeteer automation script

Tags: puppeteer

Not firing change event selecting date in react-date picker by using puppeteer.

Using below code in test js

```
await page.waitForSelector("#datepicker");    
const datepicker=await page.$("#datepicker");
await page.$$eval("input#datepicker",e=>e.value="11/05/2020") ;
await page.$$eval("input#datepicker",e=>e.blur());
```

Value is getting change in Date picker but Date change event not getting raised so data on that basis not getting change on page.

Found below solution which is working in console but not working with Puppeteer.

```
const prevalue = await page.$$eval("input#datepicker", e => e[2].value);
await page.$$eval("input#datepicker", e => e[2].value = "24/10/2019");
await page.evaluate((preval) => $("input#datepicker")[2]._valueTracker.setValue(preval), prevalue)
const event = new Event('input', {
  bubbles: true
});
await page.evaluate((eve) => $("input#datepicker")[1].dispatchEvent(eve), event);
```

Getting error:

```
Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'
```

Comment: Don't use eval, use the mouse/type functions for this. Otherwise react won't update state.

Comment: mouse/type not working. Found below solution which is working in console but not working with Puppeteer.
  const prevalue= await page.$$eval("input#datepicker",e=>e[2].value) ;
  await page.$$eval("input#datepicker",e=>e[2].value="24/10/2019") ;
  await page.evaluate((preval)=>$("input#datepicker")[2]._valueTracker.setValue(preval),prevalue)
  const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
  await page.evaluate((eve)=> $("input#datepicker")[1].dispatchEvent(eve),event);

Getting error: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'

Comment: Don't use comments to share such big chunk of code.